# Azure Datalake Gen1 connection for Azure Analysis services data models is failing by implementing via End-user authentication

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

I am using Azure Data lake Gen1 and Azure Analysis Services. I am authorizing my Azure Analysis Service's Data models with Azure Data lake connection.

For this activity, Microsoft maintains a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). I am following the same way. Based on the theory of this document I have created a PowerShell script, which executes and brings access_token & refresh token. As I get access_token & refresh_token, I update the XMLA of the Azure Analysis Services Data model connection part and deploys it.

I have tried to achieve this using the [Service to Service authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69168770/service-to-service-authentication-is-failing-for-azure-datalake-gen1-to-azure-an) mechanism but didn't work.

As I deploy and process the Same model, it fails to process the data model and gives the following error.

```
Failed to save modifications to the server. The error returned: '<pii>The credentials provided cannot be used for the datalake source. (Source at https://mydatalake.azuredatalakestore.net/.)</pii>. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

Technical Details:
RootActivityId: 46646584-7ccb-4946-a38c-b91c1963e82c
Date (UTC): 9/13/2021 7:53:10 PM
<pii>The credentials provided cannot be used for the DataLake source. (Source at https://mydatalake.azuredatalakestore.net/.)</pii>. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
<pii>The credentials provided cannot be used for the DataLake source. (Source at https://mydatalake.azuredatalakestore.net/.)</pii>. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
'.
```

**My PowerShell Script**

```
$tenantID= 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "wU8slkd)di_sadfdfjkl9*klsffkklld" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",$password)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $credential -Tenant $tenantID -ServicePrincipal

$client_secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "myvault" -Name "myUserPassword" -AsPlainText

$bodyCode = @{
    "client_id" = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "redirect_uri"="https://localhost:5000"
    "response_type"="code"
    'scope' = 'offline_access openid https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation'
}

$Query = "?"; $bodyCode.Keys | % {$Query+= "$($_)=$($bodyCode.Item($_))&"} ; $Query = $Query.TrimEnd('&')
$IE= new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$IE.Visible = $true
$IE.navigate2("https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($tenantID)/oauth2/v2.0/authorize$Query")

write-host "get authorization code"
pause

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString(([uri] $IE.LocationURL).Query)['code']
$Code = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString(([uri] $IE.LocationURL).Query)['code']
$IE.Quit()

$TokenResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($tenantID)/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Body @{
    client_id     = $bodyCode.client_id
    scope         = ''
    code          = $Code
    redirect_uri  = $bodyCode.redirect_uri
    grant_type    = 'authorization_code'
    client_secret = "wU8slkd)di_sadfdfjkl9*klsffkklld"
}

$date = Get-Date -Format r

$dataModelsList = "MY-DM-Cost-Test"
$datalakeName= 'mydatalake'
$aasName= 'asazure://aspaaseastus2.asazure.windows.net/myaas'

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$utilityCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("myUserV@company.com",$password)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $utilityCredentials -Tenant $tenantID

for($f = 0; $f -lt $dataModelsList.Count; $f++)
{
    if($dataModelsList.Count -eq 1)
    {
        $AASDatabaseName = $dataModelsList
    }
    else
    {
        $AASDatabaseName = $dataModelsList[$f]
    }


    $updateDataSource = '
    {
        "createOrReplace": {
            "object": {
                "database": "",
                "dataSource": ""
             },
             "dataSource": {
                "type": "structured",
                "name": "",
                "connectionDetails": {
                    "protocol": "data-lake-store",
                    "address": {
                        "url": ""
                    }
                },
                "options": {
                    "pageSize": 999999999
                },
                "credential": {
                    "AuthenticationKind": "OAuth2",
                    "kind": "DataLake",
                    "Expires": "",
                    "path":""
                }
            }
        }
    }'

    $DataSourcePSObject = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $updateDataSource

    $DataSourcePSObject.createOrReplace.dataSource.credential | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "RefreshToken" $TokenResult.refresh_token -Force
    $DataSourcePSObject.createOrReplace.dataSource.credential| Add-Member -NotePropertyName "AccessToken" $TokenResult.access_token -Force
    $DataSourcePSObject.createOrReplace.object.database = $AASDatabaseName
    $DataSourcePSObject.createOrReplace.object.dataSource = "DataLake/https://"+$datalakeName+ " azuredatalakestore net/"
    $DataSourcePSObject.createOrReplace.dataSource.name = "DataLake/https://"+$datalakeName+" azuredatalakestore net/"
    $DataSourcePSObject.createOrReplace.dataSource.connectionDetails.address.url = "https://"+$datalakeName+ ".azuredatalakestore.net/"
    $DataSourcePSObject.createOrReplace.dataSource.credential.Expires = $date
    $DataSourcePSObject.createOrReplace.dataSource.credential.path = "https://"+$datalakeName+".azuredatalakestore.net/"
    $jsonObject = $DataSourcePSObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 25

    $result = Invoke-ASCmd -Server $aasName -Database $AASDatabaseName -Query $jsonObject -Credential $utilityCredentials
    Write-Output "Refreshing result: $result."
}
```

**$TokenResult** returns the following values.

```
token_type     : Bearer
scope          : https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
expires_in     : 3599
ext_expires_in : 3599
access_token   : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
refresh_token  : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxx
id_token       : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

As you can see, I am getting access_token and refresh_token and injecting it into XMLA, and deploying it in Azure Analysis Service's data models.

**Please correct me where I am doing wrong? because I am injecting both access_token & refresh_token both in my Azure Analysis Service Data models.**

In, next step I open SSMS and connect Azure Analysis Service I checked the connection property and I found the following JSON.

[image]

```
{"AuthenticationKind":"OAuth2","DataSourceKind":"DataLake","Expires":"Mon, 13 Sep 2021 16:52:43 GMT","token_type":"Bearer","scope":"user_impersonation","ext_expires_in":"3599","expires_on":"3599","not_before":"3599","resource":"https://management.azure.com"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service to service authentication is failing for Azure Datalake Gen1 to Azure Analysis services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69168770/service-to-service-authentication-is-failing-for-azure-datalake-gen1-to-azure-an)

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT  I have posted two questions for two separate approaches but no suggestion is working. I am trying another approach https://files.gbrueckl.at/blog/Processing-Azure-Analysis-Services-with-_10E5D/AAS_Process_OAuth_Runbook.ps1 but this one is also giving me error. AADSTS50126 and AADSTS50056. Please help me, what is the right solution, as well as if more configuration required in existing AAD, please let me know. I will be highly obliged. I am stucking since last 3 months in this issue, client looks disappointed.